# XML with XSLT Printing in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, printing

We currently have XML Documents that use XSLT Style sheets to show detailed data in a webbrowser control. we can print these using the webbrowser's print dialog, but we need more control. The main features we need are for somehow to get the page count of the document before being printed, and the second main thing we need is to have control over the print options like choosing which tray the paper should be pulled from. I am able to do both when printing out other documents that have a PrintDocument base to work with.

We can live without the print settings portion but we really need a way to get the page count.  We don't have to use the webbrowser control if anyone can find another way around it. Currently we are just using the webrowser control to view and print the documents, we need the page count for a batch printing process so there is no need for the user to view the documents during the process.

Does anyone have anyone have an alternate way to print out XML with XSLT documents that would allow us to get the page count?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, any page count solution involving rendered HTML is going to have a very "hacky" feeling to it.  With HTML, there is no way to determine an accurate page count 100% of the time when printing.

Alternatively, there is an XML based documenting publishing standard known as XSL:FO that you could use in a similar fashion to what you are currently doing (instead of XML & XSLT -> HTML, its XML & XSLT -> XSL:FO),  however it typically requires the use of a third party renderer like http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo.htm

Comment: Yea I know its going to be a hacky solution but that is fine. we just need to get something to work. With the print document class you can send a print job and there is an event called OnPrintPage that I can stick a counter in and then cancel the print job before a print is actually sent to the printer. Something like this would be fine but unfortunately Microsoft gives you almost no control over printing from a web browser control.

Comment: The third party option is not really a possibility right now. we have a lot of things happening that rely on the current configuration